# Is it possible to find out which option is highlighted in IE before it is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I know from many other SO questions that IE does not support mouse events on `<option>` elements. However, when you open a dropdown list it does highlight the option under the mouse cursor. Is there a JS way to get this highlighted option as the user flicks the mouse over it? If there is, there should be an added benefit that it would work with the keyboard cursor keys too (maybe).

I have found a boolean property `selected` on each `<option>` which is `true` if the mouse cursor is on it in Firefox but the same trick unfortunately doesn't work in IE.

Even using jQuery's `$("option").filter(":selected")` doesn't work in IE but does in FF. In IE the `<option>` only becomes selected *after* the user has chosen it; it's basically the value of the parent `<select>` element.

Any other ways to get the "almost" selected `<option>` in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Every browser render dropdowns differently. So to attach event handlers with different options shows different results in Firefox, and different in IE. This will also show similar result in Chrome.

I suggest you could use JavaScript or Jquery to create Dropdown using HTML elements on Fly, i.e during runtime.

Don't create while you create webpage. Try this code, it may work.

```
$(function() {
    $("#optionList").change(function(){
            alert("Mouse Hover Fired");
    });
});
```

Comment: What element is `#optionList`? Is that the parent `<select>`?

Comment: That event doesn't fire until the option is clicked on in IE.